# Github for the second user: how to set up

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-remote

I've tried to setup a second user for github. I followed [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) article, created SSH key, tied it to my github.com accound and added remote origin.

How do I proceed from this moment on? When I use

`git config user.name
git config user.email`

commands it still dispays the 1st account's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user.name/email have nothing to do with authentication. Only with commit authorship.

Check if your second key is cirrectly recognized by GitHub:

```
ssh -T github-COMPANY
```

(with github-COMPANY the key in your ~/.ssh/config file, which references your second private key, provided your registered your second public key to your second GitHub account)

If this works (you get a Welcome message), then in your second local repo, use that URL:

```
git remote set-url origin github-COMPANY:<secondUser>/<secondRepo>
```

And push.